# How to make Ada math function use double precision (Long float)variables?

Tags: math, double, ada

Ada's standard math functions such as sin, cos, *, /, etc support Float type variables only as input and output.  Is it possible to make these functions deal with double precision or long_float for both input and output variables?

Comment: What you think of as "Ada's standard math functions" is actually a predefined instantiation of Ada's standard math-function package for type Float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually math functions are (fortunately) supported for any precision.

```
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;

...

  type Real is digits 15;

  package REF is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions (Real);

  use REF;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should find

- `Ada.Numerics.Long_Elementary_Functions` (for `Long_Float`)
- `Ada.Numerics.Short_Elementary_Functions` (for `Short_Float`)

as well as

- `Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions` (for `Float`).

See [ARM A.5.1(9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-5-1.html#p9).